# Bash Script - Sed Command

Tags: bash, unix, sed

I created a script to add 100 space characters at the end of each line:

```
#!/bin/ksh
sed -i -e 's/\n/            - 100 spaces  -                         /' $1
```

but it doesn't work and I think it is because of `\n`. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sed processes the content of the lines *without* the newline. Your code never sees a newline, so it cannot replace it.

Match the end of the string:

```
sed -i -e 's/$/ - 100 spaces - /' $1
```

Answer (score 1):

Although Karoly has already pointed out the error in your script, you could also save yourself typing 100 spaces by using a condition and break to make a sort of loop

```
sed ':1;/ \{100\}$/!{s/$/ /;b1}' file
```

Will print 100 space at the end of the line

If there are already spaces at the end and you want to add 100

```
sed 's/$/1/;:1;/1 \{100\}$/!{s/$/ /;b1};s/1\( *\)$/\1/' file
```

Comment: But it will not *add* 100 if there were already some; it will stop when there are 100 spaces.

Comment: @tripleee added one for that.

Comment: Or you could use printf:  `sed "s/\$/$(printf ' %.0s' {1..100})/" file`

Comment: @A.Danischewski Yep! i try to avoid embedding commands in sed though as it tends to be a bit flaky.

Comment: @123 Yea, if you open that style door it can turn into a can of worms. You could programmatically generate it with an `echo "sed \"s/\$/$(printf ' %.0s' {1..100})/\""` and I would put a comment above what the space count is so you don't have to waste any time later.

Answer (score 0):

Just a suggestion to avoid typing 100 spaces (although I'm sure that by this time, you already have!) - use perl:

```
perl -pe 's/$/" " x 100/e' file
```

As the other answers have stated, this matches the end of the line and replaces with 100 spaces, using the `e` modifier to allow you to write `" " x 100` and let perl do the work for you.

As with sed, you can modify the file in-place using the `-i` switch - as with sed, I'd suggest using something like `-i.bak` to create a backup file `file.bak`.

Answer (score 0):

Could be the `\n` as that's undefined by POSIX and so implementation dependent across seds but you also say you want add spaces to the end of a line while your script is trying to replace the end of line with spaces.

In any case this is not a job for sed, just use `[s]printf("%100s","")` in awk to create a string of 100 blanks, e.g.:

```
$ echo "foo bar" | awk '{printf "%s%10s%s\n", $1, "", $2}'
foo          bar
```